# How to merge values into an String format

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merging Values into an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568998/merging-values-into-an-array)

Comment: duplicate! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format

Comment: Does this have anything to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568998/merging-values-into-an-array?

Answer (score 4):

Do you have control over the names of these variables? If so, I would change their structure like so:

```
var names = {
    AppointmentSearchDays: 'aaa',
    AppointmentSearchDaysBefore: 'bbb',
    PrimeSuiteId: 'ccc'    
};

var values = {
    AppointmentSearchDays: 3333,
    AppointmentSearchDaysBefore: 5,
    PrimeSuiteId: 10 
};
```

This would allow you to merge them like so:

```
var arr = [];
for (var key in names) {
    if (names.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        arr.push(names[key] + ' ' + values[key]);
    }
}

arr.join(',');
```

If you wanted to get real bold, you could do this:

```
var values = {
    AppointmentSearchDays: { key: 'aaa', value: 3333 },
    AppointmentSearchDaysBefore: { key: 'bbb', value: 5 }
    PrimeSuiteId: { key: 'ccc', value: 10 }
};


var arr = [];
for (var i = 0, len = values.length; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(values[i].key + ' ' + values[i].value);
}

arr.join(',');
```

Comment: +1 I was just typing the same thing :-) you can call var result = arr.join(); //comma is the default delimiter

Comment: +1 Nice approach for pairing output. Overkill otherwise ;)

Answer (score 2):

I may be over simplifying the question, but just use the native concatenation operator `+`.

```
var format = var AppointmentSearchDaysAfter
 + ' '
 + AppointmentSearchDaysAfterValue
 + ','
 + AppointmentSearchDaysBefore
 + ' '
 + AppointmentSearchDaysBeforeValue
 + ','
 + PrimeSuiteId
 + ' '
 + PrimeSuiteIdValue
alert(format);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You would just append all of the values using the '+' operator:**

**Actual String :**

```
var result = AppointmentSearchDaysAfter + " " + AppointmentSearchDaysAfterValue + "," +AppointmentSearchDaysBefore + " " + AppointmentSearchDaysBeforeValue  + "," + PrimeSuiteId + " " + PrimeSuiteIdValue;
```

**Readible String :**

```
var result = AppointmentSearchDaysAfter + " " + 
                 AppointmentSearchDaysAfterValue + "," +
                 AppointmentSearchDaysBefore + " " + 
                 AppointmentSearchDaysBeforeValue  + "," + 
                 PrimeSuiteId + " " + 
                 PrimeSuiteIdValue;
```